# Strange behavior of sum function

Tags: r

I have a vector `v1` within a dataframe `df`. Looking at the data with `summary(v1)` shows the following:

```
Min.   1st Qu.    Median   Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0         7        16     15649     26      100000000
```

I am trying to clean up the data and see that about 2% of the values are 0 with `sum(df$v1==0)/nrow(df)`. But when I try the same thing for the maximum values, I am getting no results:

```
sum(df$v1==100000000)/nrow(df)
[1] 0
```

I know this is not the case since at least 10 values are 10,000,000 per

```
tail(sort(df$v1),10)
[1] 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08
```

Any idea what is going on and how I can see the number of extreme values? Does R store such values in some way I don't know about (the data is likely from formulas that have a divide by zero)?

Comment: could be floating point - try round(df$v1) ==100000000

Comment: Can you verify that the code you are running is actually giving the output you show? For one thing, the function is `nrow`, not `nrows`, and it returns `NULL` when used on a vector as opposed to a dataframe which will give unexpected results when you divide by it

Comment: `sum(df$v1==max(df$v1))` should do it. Also this is not a problem with `sum()` as much as with `==`, or more likely - machine precision for floating point numbers.

Comment: Computers don't store numbers as accurately as we think they do. This behaviour is similar across any programming languages I've worked with and occasionally get caught by it still....

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius and Euler's..., I suggest that when dealing with `numeric`, in general you should assume *equality* will be unreliable due to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and IEEE-754. It would be better (more defensive and defensible) to test for *inequality* and/or tolerance (with inequality). For instance, `sum(df$v1 > (1e8-1))` (where the `1` is really arbitrary here). To get just those instances, then `abs(df$v1 - 1e8) < eps` where `eps` is some small-enough number, e.g., `1e-12`.